# Slider which can open picture in fullscreen with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, slider, fancybox-2

I tried using Nivo Slider (3.2) with fancybox (2.1.4). Here I have two problems:

-By clicking on the image I can only view the same size image as in the slider
-Nivo slider image disappears in background when fancybox is open

I used

```
$(".nivo-main-image").fancybox();
```

So is there a slider which can do this? Or do I have to write my custom slider? The slider should show the circles (amount of slides) as the Nivo slider and should have next/prev buttons. Also I want the option that no automatic transition takes place.

Comment: It's not the slider, is the way you initialize fancybox: how do you tell fancybox what image to open? I assume you want to open a bigger image but if you don't set a target, then fancybox will move the visible image (in the slider) to the light-box as inline content. I guess you should set a `data-fancybox-href="{big image target}"` attribute to your images in the slider so fancybox will know what to show.

Comment: I take the representing main image which is displayed to the user. It is the only image which is clickable by the user. The nivo slider doesn't adopt the class or your data attribute ...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to JFK:

```
function setFullImage(){
    var src = $(".nivo-main-image").attr('src');
    var image = $("img[src$='" + src + "']");
    var full = image.attr("data-fancybox-href");
    $(".nivo-main-image").attr("data-fancybox-href", full);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        animSpeed:500,
        pauseTime:3000,
        startSlide:0,
        directionNav:true,
        controlNav:true,
        controlNavThumbs:false,
        pauseOnHover:true,
        manualAdvance:false,
        //afterLoad: function(){$('#slider').data('nivo:vars').stop = true;},
        afterLoad: function(){setFullImage();},
        afterChange: function(){setFullImage();}
    });
    $('#slider').data('nivoslider').stop();
    $(".nivo-main-image").fancybox();
});
```